# iOS app groups not making sense

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ios-app-group

I must have misunderstood something very basic regarding iOS App groups  somewhere. Please help me getmy head around it. :-)

As I understand iOS App Groups they can be used for two (or more) apps to share some data, such as files or user preferences.

Now, to make this work this needs to be set up:

1. An App group must be registered and given an identity with the team's developer portal (example: `group.com.mycompany.myappgroup`)
2. An App Id must be set up in the dev portal that allows app groups and that references the set up app group id (example: `com.mycompany.myappgroup`)
3. A provisioning profile must be registered that references the new App Id
4. Each app needs to be signed with a Bundle Id that corresponds to the App Id (example: `com.mycompany.myappgroup`)

Now, what I don't understand is the last item. If apps needs to have bundle id's that matches the same App Id then they would no longer be uniquely identifiable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

every app has it own app id .. so every app still has a different bundle id.

the app id is something different... it's not the app group id and would be com.mycompany.myapp or com.mycompany.myotherapp or something like that.

I'm pretty sure that just means you can't sign the apps with wildcard bundle certificates like com.mycompany.*. Every app needs to be signed with a certificate matching the apps id.

Comment: But aren't multiple apps supposed to be able to share the same App id (and, thus, provisioning profile)? If not, how could App groups work?

Comment: no .. every app needs it's own app id. you can add an app group to the app in xcode. the app group id has nothing to do with the app id. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html